# T-SQL stored procedure does not return zero by COUNT(*) on an empty SELECT result

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am using the Spring Framework's `StoredProcedure` (I am extending it, of course) to get a result set and an output parameter (`@totalRowsReturned`) which is an Integer. The problem is that when the resultset being returned is supposed to be an empty list, I am getting a `NullPointerException` when I try to retrieve the output parameter (totalRows, which naively I would expect it to be zero).

I would like to mention that the code works fine when the result set being found is not empty.

**My questions are:**

1. Why isn't `@totalRowsReturned` being set to zero in this case? (Or in case it is, why can't I retrieve it through the Java code?)
2. How can I make this code (Java code + T-SQL code) work in such a way that `@totalRowsReturned` will be set to zero when required, and I could retrieve it through the Java code?

**Dao:**

```
List<Book> books = null;
int totalRows = 0;

Map<String, Object> results = storedProcedure.execute(parameters);
books = (List<Book>) results.get("rs");
totalRows = (Integer) results.get("totalRowsReturned"); // NullPointerException on this line if total rows are supposed to be zero!!
```

**T-SQL stored procedure:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Find_Books

    @authorName Varchar(250),   
    @totalRowsReturned INTEGER OUTPUT

AS

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SelectQuery NVARCHAR(2000)

    SET @SelectQuery = 'SELECT @totalRows=COUNT(*) OVER() FROM book b WHERE b.author_name = @authorName'

    Execute sp_Executesql @SelectQuery, N'@authorName VARCHAR(250), @totalRows int OUTPUT', @authorName, @totalRows=@totalRowsReturned OUTPUT

-- Select resultset goes here...

END
```

**UPDATE:**

Actually, my stored procedure looks more like this (the change is the additional **`@first_id = b.book_id`** in the SELECT):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Find_Books

    @authorName Varchar(250),   
    @totalRowsReturned INTEGER OUTPUT

AS

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SelectQuery NVARCHAR(2000)

    DECLARE @first_id int
    DECLARE @first_id_local_returned int

    SET @SelectQuery = 'SELECT @first_id = b.book_id, @totalRows=COUNT(*) OVER() FROM book b WHERE b.author_name = @authorName'

    Execute sp_Executesql @SelectQuery, N'@authorName VARCHAR(250), @first_id int OUTPUT, @totalRows int OUTPUT', @authorName, @first_id=@first_id_local_returned OUTPUT, @totalRows=@totalRowsReturned OUTPUT

    -- Select resultset goes here... I am using the value of @first_id_local_returned in this SELECT...

END
```

The problem is, that when there are no rows returned from the SELECT, b.book_id is not defined, so I get an **`org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException ... Column 'book.book_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`**

So it seems like if I keep the `OVER()`, then `@totalRows=COUNT(*) OVER()` fails when there are zero rows returned, and if I remove the `OVER()`, then `@first_id = b.book_id` fails.

Any idea how I overcome this?

Comment: Your `WHERE` and `FROM` seem to be the wrong way around. Also why are you using `COUNT(*) OVER()` rather than just  `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: Try to remove `OVER()`. When you use `OVER()` and have no hits you will get no rows. Without `OVER()` you will always get 1 row.

Comment: @Martin Smith - I am sorry - it was my typo. I have just corrected my question. As I said above, the code works fine for cases other than zero rows.

Comment: @rapt. It works for those cases but inefficiently. It repeatedly reassigns the same value to the variable. You should just use `COUNT(*)` to get a single row result.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson - I do not think I got you. When there are no hits I do want to get no rows: no hits, this means zero results, and zero rows. Without `OVER()` - why would I want to get 1 row when there are zero rows? - And what is there in that one row?

Comment: @rapt - Try running the query on its own without the `@totalRows=` variable assignment and look at the results. It should be obvious then that `COUNT(*)` is preferable to `COUNT(*) OVER()`. The second one gives you as many rows as the value of the `COUNT`. You always need 1 row. Any more is a complete waste of effort. Any less leaves your variable unassigned.

Comment: Why are you using SQL to generate dynamic SQL in this way? sp_ExecuteSQL appears to be completely unnecessary in this case.

Comment: @David Lively - I am trying to understand where a more complicated case fails. I simplified my code to make the question more to the point.

Comment: @rapt - I mean that the result set of your query should always have one row. The value on that row is the count of rows your query returns. It should be one row with the value `0` if there are no hits for the query and if there are `3` hits there should be one row with the value `3`. The value is what you assign to your variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COUNT(*) OVER ()` is not the correct thing to use here. Just use `COUNT(*)`

`COUNT(*) OVER ()` returns a result set with as many rows as the `COUNT`. e.g if the result is 3 the result set will be

```
3
3
3
```

The effect of your query is then to repeatedly re-assign the value `3` to the `@totalRows` variable as many times as there are rows which is completely pointless.

Conversely if `COUNT(*) = 0` then the `COUNT(*) OVER ()` result set is empty so your variable is never assigned to at all.

`COUNT(*)` will always give you a single row scalar resultset here that you can assign to the variable and will have a more efficient execution plan without unnecessary common subexpression spools too.

**Edit**

In response to your question in the comments. This does the same thing as your linked article. It can use a narrower index to find the (say) 10,000th Employee then joins onto Department only for the 1 subsequent page of records. This paging method only works correctly because each employee has exactly one department.

```
WITH E1(RN, EmployeeID)
     AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmployeeID),
                EmployeeID
         FROM   Employees)
SELECT TOP (@maximumRows) e.*,
                          d.Name AS DepartmentName
FROM   Employees e
       INNER JOIN Departments d
         ON e.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
WHERE  EmployeeID >= (SELECT EmployeeID
                      FROM   E1
                      WHERE  RN = @startRowIndex)
ORDER  BY e.EmployeeID
```

Comment: Thank you - a very clear explanation. I did not know that `OVER()` will independently create a row for every aggregated row even if there are no other columns being selected - I usually used it with other columns being selected so I thought the `COUNT(*) OVER()` value etc is replicated in each row just because there are multiple rows due to the `select columns` (I think this is why `COUNT(*)` is replicated over multiple rows when other columns are being selected).

Comment: Regarding the multiple re-assignment with `@totalRows=COUNT(*) OVER()` - I read here http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/042606-1.shtml that actually this isn't true and the assignment will happen only once, and even more than this: the table will be hit by much less than `COUNT(*)` reads. "...SQL Server doesn't actually get all of the records from the table, one at a time, and assign them to the local variable. Rather, it searches just for the last record in the query and assigns that result to the variable." -- your idea on this? Also, please see my **UPDATE** above.

Comment: @rapt - That quote is definitely not correct. SQL Server does no such optimisation. The author there is confused about what a read is. They seem to be assuming that a table with 100 rows will be expected to have 100 reads. In fact a logical read refers to the number of **pages** read not rows. So that part is nonsense. Regarding your edited question you need to put the `bookid` expression in an aggregate such as `MIN` or `MAX` assuming it is arbitrary which bookid you want returned.

Comment: Thank you, great answer - and it solved the issue. But could you explain the results shown in the Reads column at the table at the bottom of the above mentioned article? The numbers are very impressive so I am wondering what they represent.

Comment: logical reads are the number of 8KB data or index pages read. See my edit for more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an aggregate function on `b.book_id`.

You can use `min()`

```
SELECT @first_id = min(b.book_id), @totalRows=COUNT(*) FROM book ...
```

or `max()` if that is more appropriate in your case

```
SELECT @first_id = max(b.book_id), @totalRows=COUNT(*) FROM book ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but I think it's something like this (you really don't want/need dynamic SQL in this case):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Find_Books
    @authorName Varchar(250),   
    @totalRowsReturned INTEGER OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @totalRowsReturned = SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM book b WHERE b.author_name = @authorName
    SELECT b.book_id 
        FROM book b WHERE b.author_name = @authorName
END
```